# Adaptação de postagens em colunas usando Flexbox

Tags: php, wordpress, temas

Tudo bem galera? Seguinte eu tenho um site que preciso chamar as últimas postagens de uma categoria de id=3 dentro de 2 linhas com 3 colunas na home, algo que seria muito fácil usando bootstrap repetindo 6 div com classe ".col-sm-4" por exemplo.
Porém no meu caso tenho uma div com 3 colunas e cada coluna tem 2 imagens uma abaixo da outra e na do meio é maior a altura e largura, só o html e css já fiz, a chamada também ta sendo feita mas queria chamar 2 por vez em cada coluna e na do meio chamaria a classe que faria ela aumentar.
Atualmente está assim como no anexo chamado teste.jpg e queria que ficasse igual no index.png!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Link do site: http://vencimeumonstro.com.br

Comment: Olá Rudi. Coloque o código que você já tem, assim podemos ajudar melhor que pelas imagens.

Comment: Olá ainda não sei fazer isso aqui, mas eu consegui resolver de uma maneira diferente, ta funcionando já, ralei a cuca mas descobri kkk. Não sei colocar como RESOLVIDO aqui na pergunta nem editar a pergunta!

Comment: Escreva qual foi a soua solução na resposta, pra que outras pessoas possam ver como você resolveu, depois clique em "aceitar" a sua própria resposta

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde galera, acabei resolvendo criando uma div com display flex com wrap. E dentro dessa div criei 3 colunas e cada coluna tem 2 artigos dentro. No meio criei uma classe especial para os artigos serem maiores q os das pontas!
Podem ver no site:
http://vencimeumonstro.com.br/